# htaccess redirect subdomain wrong url

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website for which I redirect to the public directory as I am using lavarel. However, today I want to create a different website on a subdomain I created "sub.domain.com" but when I visit the url "sub.domain.com" it redirects to "sub.domain.com/public" I dont want this new website on my subdomain to use the htaccess redirect for public that uses my main domain website. I want my sub domain to have its own website and not use the redirect of public.

here is what i have on my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /public/ [B,L]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the â€œea-php81â€ package as the default â€œPHPâ€ programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php81 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

I figured that if I just created a director called "events" it would use the htaccess on root and redirect to public which is the problem I am having even when I didnt create a directory, I created a sub domain which has a directory named "events.domain.com" inside root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another `.htaccess` in the subdomains document root (ie. the subdirectory inside the main domains document root) and disable (or enable) the rewrite engine:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

This prevents the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file (that are processed along the directory path) from being processed.

You can also enable the rewrite engine (if you need to do some rewriting/redirecting for the subdomain), since mod_rewrite is not inherited by default.

Although, if the subdomain does not have anything to do with the main domain then it should not be pointing to a subdirectory off the main domain’s document root in the first place. You then wouldn’t have these issues.

Comment: The RewriteEngine Off worked. The subdomain is on the main domain, but I have a rewrite on main domain pointing to /public directory which is where all website assets are. The problem was that even on the subdomain it would point to /public directory when no /public directory exists on sub domain only main domain.